# Show wordpress custom field in index page

Tags: wordpress

I codding a website and i show last recent posts of specially Cat on

```html
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10&cat=2');
while ($my_query->have_posts()):
$my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

<div class=image><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?></div>
<div class=title><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>

        <---here--->
        
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

i want where i wroted <---here---> show my recent posts custom fields

Like : Price

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this code in <---here--->

```
<?php $price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field_name', true ); ?>
```

here, 'custom_field_name' = price // your custom field name.

Comment: my mistake in use php echo :)